# Prod and Dev environment in nodejs

Tags: node.js, rest, api, express, environment

*** I am a beginner of nodejs, hope can give me some advice, thank you so much :)

I have one server to run my nodejs application (REST API).

My application have two environment (development and production),
i update the code in development quite frequent to do testing,
after i complete the development, i will release the code to production.

I am using pm2 in nodejs to run the application.
Here is the folder structure of my REST API

- restapi

  - app1
  - node_modules
  - db.js
  - ....
    index.js

Here is my question:
What is the best way to setup the dev and prod environment for my app?

I have two idea
**Idea 1:**
Put prod and dev seperate to two folder, both listening to same port and run as single service
prod: www.xxx.com:8080/app_dev/
dev:  www.xxx.com:8080/app_prod/

- restapi

  - app_dev
  - node_modules
  - db.js
  - ....
  - app_prod
  - node_modules
  - db.js
  - ....
    index.js

**Idea 2:**
prod: www.xxx.com:8080/app/

dev:  www.xxx.com:8081/app/

Run as two services, listening to different port.

In my server, i just need to seperate two folder:

- dev
- prod

I can always change the code in dev and restart the app and never impact prod

Comment: First of all I want to understand that how are you treating development environment and production environment ? Are you developing on different git branches or have you made two separate files for setting the configuration like development.js and production.js  ??

Comment: I recommend using two separate ports for development and production server. This will keep things simple and flexible.

Comment: @amanpurohit i developing on different git branches, development branch and master branch, after i complete the development, i will merge to master branch. After i merge it, i will go to my server and git pull the latest code in production folder, then reload my app. I got another folder is development folder, i can git pull from development branch to do testing.

Comment: @OngKahKit You are on the right track. I would also suggest you the same way. Keep going !

Answer (score 0):

If you want to deploy your application to a public web host, there might be a bit more steps to take. You can have a look at [this guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Express_Nodejs/deployment), which proposes a deployment solution using *Heroku*.